# Accessing a specific layer in a pretrained model in PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, pre-trained-model

I want to extract the features from certain blocks of the [TimeSformer](https://github.com/facebookresearch/TimeSformer) model and also want to remove the last two layers.

```
import torch
from timesformer.models.vit import TimeSformer

model = TimeSformer(img_size=224, num_classes=400, num_frames=8, attention_type='divided_space_time',  pretrained_model='/path/to/pretrained/model.pyth')
```

The print of the model is as follows:

```
TimeSformer(
  (model): VisionTransformer(
(dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
(patch_embed): PatchEmbed(
  (proj): Conv2d(3, 768, kernel_size=(16, 16), stride=(16, 16))
)
(pos_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
(time_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
(blocks): ModuleList(  #************
  (0): Block(
    (norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (attn): Attention(
      (qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
      (proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
      (attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    )
    (temporal_norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (temporal_attn): Attention(
      (qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
      (proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
      (attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    )
    (temporal_fc): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
    (drop_path): Identity()
    (norm2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (mlp): Mlp(
      (fc1): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
      (act): GELU()
      (fc2): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    )
  )
  (1): Block(
    (norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (attn): Attention(
      (qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
      (proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
      (attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    )
    (temporal_norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (temporal_attn): Attention(
      (qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
      (proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
      (attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    )
    (temporal_fc): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
    (drop_path): DropPath()
    (norm2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (mlp): Mlp(
      (fc1): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
      (act): GELU()
      (fc2): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    )
  )
.
.
.
.
.
.
  (11): Block(
    (norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (attn): Attention(
      (qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
      (proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
      (attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    )
    (temporal_norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (temporal_attn): Attention(
      (qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
      (proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
      (attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    )
    (temporal_fc): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
    (drop_path): DropPath()
    (norm2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (mlp): Mlp(
      (fc1): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
      (act): GELU()
      (fc2): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    )
  )
)
(norm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True) **** I want to remove this layer*****
(head): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=400, bias=True) **** I want to remove this layer*****
```

)

)

Specifically, I want to extract the outputs of the 4th, 8th and 11th blocks of the model and removing the lats two layers. How can I do this. I tried using TimeSformer.blocks[0] but that was not working.

Update :

I have a Class and I need to access the aforementioned blocks of the TimeSformer as the output of this class. The input of this class is a 5D tensor. This is the non-modified code that I use for extracting the outputs of the aforementioned blocks:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, pretrained=False):
    super(Model, self).__init__()
    
    
    self.model =TimeSformer(img_size=224, num_classes=400, num_frames=8, attention_type='divided_space_time',  
                                       pretrained_model='/home/user/models/TimeSformer_divST_16x16_448_K400.pyth')
    
   
    self.activation = {}
    def get_activation(name):
        def hook(model, input, output):
            self.activation[name] = output.detach()
            return hook

    self.model.model.blocks[4].register_forward_hook(get_activation('block4'))
    self.model.model.blocks[8].register_forward_hook(get_activation('block8'))
    self.model.model.blocks[11].register_forward_hook(get_activation('block11'))


    block4_output = self.activation['block4']
    block8_output = self.activation['block8']
    block11_output = self.activation['block11']
    
    
    
def forward(self, x, out_consp = False):
    
    features2, features3, features4 = self.model(x)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To extract the intermediate output from specific layers, you can register it as a hook, the example is showed by the snipcode below:

```py
import torch
from timesformer.models.vit import TimeSformer

model = TimeSformer(img_size=224, num_classes=400, num_frames=8, attention_type='divided_space_time',  pretrained_model='/path/to/pretrained/model.pyth')

activation = {}
def get_activation(name):
    def hook(model, input, output):
        activation[name] = output.detach()
    return hook

model.model.blocks[4].register_forward_hook(get_activation('block4'))
model.model.blocks[8].register_forward_hook(get_activation('block8'))
model.model.blocks[11].register_forward_hook(get_activation('block11'))

x = torch.randn(3,3,224,224)
output = model(x)

block4_output = activation['block4']
block8_output = activation['block8']
block11_output = activation['block11']
```

To remove the last two layers, you can replace them with Identity:

```py
model.norm = torch.nn.Identity()
model.head= torch.nn.Identity()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am facing this error: name 'activation' is not defined.
Moreover, the blocks that I need to extract output of them are inside a ModuleList that I highlighted the ModuleList with ****** . I thinks the code cannot access the blocks because of the structure of the model. In contrast to the resnet model that layers are sequential, the TimeSformer model blocks are inside a ModuleList.

Comment: if you try to init it in a class, please set `activation` as `self.activation` else I can't understand why that error comes up.  The ModuleList is also able to interact with, just call the index of the block is fine, can you edit the question and upload your full code

Comment: I added the code that I want use your answer in it. Sorry the whole amount of the codes are so large. As a question, in the case it is needed, how it is possible to access for example  the  (proj) layer of the 1st Block.