# Accessing a module inside of a block in a pretrained model

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, pre-trained-model

How can I access the output of a specific layer in a specific block of a pretrained model. To be clearer, the print of the [TimeSformer](https://github.com/facebookresearch/TimeSformer) model is as follows:

The print of the model is as follows:

```
TimeSformer(
  (model): VisionTransformer(
(dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
(patch_embed): PatchEmbed(
  (proj): Conv2d(3, 768, kernel_size=(16, 16), stride=(16, 16))
)
(pos_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
(time_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
(blocks): ModuleList(  
  (0): Block(
    (norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (attn): Attention(
      (qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
      (proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
      (attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    )
    (temporal_norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (temporal_attn): Attention(
      (qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
      (proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
      (attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    )
    (temporal_fc): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
    (drop_path): Identity()
    (norm2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (mlp): Mlp(
      (fc1): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
      (act): GELU()
      (fc2): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    )
  )
  (1): Block(
    (norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (attn): Attention(
      (qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
      (proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
      (attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    )
    (temporal_norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (temporal_attn): Attention(  # *********
      (qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
      (proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True) # @@@@@@@
      (proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
      (attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    )
    (temporal_fc): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
    (drop_path): DropPath()
    (norm2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (mlp): Mlp(
      (fc1): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
      (act): GELU()
      (fc2): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    )
  )
.
.
.
.
.
.
  (11): Block(
    (norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (attn): Attention(
      (qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
      (proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
      (attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    )
    (temporal_norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (temporal_attn): Attention(
      (qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
      (proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
      (attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    )
    (temporal_fc): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
    (drop_path): DropPath()
    (norm2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (mlp): Mlp(
      (fc1): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
      (act): GELU()
      (fc2): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    )
  )
)
(norm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True) 
(head): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=400, bias=True)
```

)

Based on the answer that was proposed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73105581/11140344) it is possible to have the access to the output of a block:

```
    import torch
from timesformer.models.vit import TimeSformer

model = TimeSformer(img_size=224, num_classes=400, num_frames=8, attention_type='divided_space_time',  pretrained_model='/path/to/pretrained/model.pyth')

activation = {}
def get_activation(name):
    def hook(model, input, output):
        activation[name] = output.detach()
    return hook

model.model.blocks[4].register_forward_hook(get_activation('block4'))
model.model.blocks[8].register_forward_hook(get_activation('block8'))
model.model.blocks[11].register_forward_hook(get_activation('block11'))

x = torch.randn(3,3,224,224)
output = model(x)

block4_output = activation['block4']
block8_output = activation['block8']
block11_output = activation['block11']
```

My question is that how can I have access to a module inside the blocks or a layer inside of a module of a block that are represented by * and @ signs. To be clearer, How can I have access the output of the `(temporal_attn)` and also output of the `(proj)` that is inside of the `(temporal_attn)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having access to those blocks, you can easily proceed with accessing the sub-modules via the dot notation assuming those blocks are custom `nn.Module` (*i.e.* they are not subscriptable and the bracket notation can't be used). For instance with block n°4:

```
>>> model.model.blocks[4].temporal_attn \
       .register_forward_hook(get_activation('attn_block4'))

>>> model.model.blocks[4].temporal_attn.proj \ 
       .register_forward_hook(get_activation('attn_proj_block4'))
```